# Cross-posts from Stack Overflow to CR

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange

What this code does it explained in detail in the top portion of the query.

I have left out part of the list of language tags as I felt it was just noise. You can see the [full collection here](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/330823/collections-of-categorized-tags).

You can run **[this query on SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/411872/cross-posts-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review)** and play with it as you wish.

Note that I left plenty of wiggle room for others to modify and aggregate their own data starting from the simple query at the bottom.

> 1089 rows returned in 5886 ms

How could I improve this with regards to readability, performance, etc.?

```
/**
 * The objective of this query is to gather data related to cross-posts from
 *   Stack Overflow (SO) to Code Review (CR). A cross-post as defined in this context is
 *   a question which has first been asked on SO and then a short time later asked
 *   again on CR (albeit often slightly modified in the way it is titled or phrased).
 * Querying from 2 or more sites requires cross-database queries, and the following
 *   2 databases are used here. All relevant tables are in the [dbo] schema.
 * - Stack Overflow DB: [StackOverflow]
 * - Code Review DB:    [StackExchange.Codereview]
 * 2 temporary tables are used in order to compensate for the physsical limitations
 *   of SEDE which otherwise will often time out before the query is completed.
 * param @minutesFromSoPostToCrPost int not null : The number of minutes allowed between the original
 *   SO question and its cross-post on CR. Default 120 minutes.
 * param @maximumCharacterCountDifferenceAllowed int not null : The maximum number
 *   of characters difference between the body of the question.
 *   NOTE: The higher the number, the more likely that it's not actually a cross-post.
 */
if object_id('tempdb..#LanguageTags') is not null
    drop table #LanguageTags;
if object_id('tempdb..#CrossPosts') is not null
    drop table #CrossPosts;
go
create table #LanguageTags (
    TagName varchar(35) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
    , constraint pk_#LanguageTags primary key (TagName)
);
go
insert into #LanguageTags (TagName)
values
  ('applescript'),
  ('asp.net-mvc-3'),
  ('bash'),
  ('brainfuck'),
  ('c'),
  ('c#'),
  ('c++'),

  /*SNIP...*/

  ('sql'),
  ('swift'),
  ('wolfram-mathematica'),
  ('xslt');
go
declare @questionPost int = 1;
declare @minutesFromSoPostToCrPost int = 120;
declare @maximumCharacterCountDifferenceAllowed int = 1000;

select
    [Primary Stack] = case
        when SoUsers.Reputation >= CrUsers.Reputation then 
            'Stack Overflow'
        else 
            'Code Review' 
        end
  , [Primary User] = case
        when SoUsers.Reputation >= CrUsers.Reputation then
            'http://stackoverflow.com/users/' + convert(varchar(10), SoUsers.Id) + '|' + SoUsers.DisplayName
        else 
            'http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/' + convert(varchar(10), CrUsers.Id) + '|' + CrUsers.DisplayName 
        end
        , [SO Original] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/' + convert(varchar(10), SoPosts.Id) + '|' + SoPosts.Title
        , [CR Xpost] = 'http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/' + convert(varchar(10), CrPosts.Id) + '|' + CrPosts.Title
  /*Calculate the character difference of the body of both questions.*/
  , [CharCountDiff] = abs(len(CrPosts.Body) - len(SoPosts.Body))
  , [SO Score] = SoPosts.Score
  , [CR Score] = CrPosts.Score
  , [SO Status] = case
        when SoPosts.DeletionDate is not null then 'Deleted'
        when SoPosts.ClosedDate is not null then 'Closed'
        else 'OK' end
  , [CR Status] = case
        when CrPosts.DeletionDate is not null then 'Deleted'
        when CrPosts.ClosedDate is not null then 'Closed'
        else 'OK' end
  /*Check in @Duga comments*/
  , [DugaComments?] = case
        when exists (
            select 1 from [StackOverflow].dbo.Comments as SoComments
            where SoPosts.Id = SoComments.PostId
            and SoComments.Text like '%code%review%'
        ) then 'True' end
  , [SO Answers] = SoPosts.AnswerCount
  , [CR Answers] = CrPosts.AnswerCount
  , [SO Accept?] = case 
        when SoPosts.AcceptedAnswerId is not null then 'True' end
  , [CR Accept?] = case 
        when CrPosts.AcceptedAnswerId is not null then 'True' end
  , [SO Created] = SoPosts.CreationDate
  , [Minutes to Xpost] = datediff(minute, SoPosts.CreationDate, CrPosts.CreationDate)
  , [Tags] = CrPosts.Tags

/*Adding results into temp table to avoid timeouts in `select distinct`*/
into #CrossPosts
from
    /*Common users across CR and SO sites:*/
    [StackExchange.Codereview].dbo.Users as CrUsers
    inner join [StackOverflow].dbo.Users as SoUsers
        /*AccountId is network-wide Id for each user, and
          is distinct from the UserId which is for a specific site*/
        on  CrUsers.AccountId = SoUsers.AccountId

    /*Questions by user on both sites:*/
    inner join [StackExchange.Codereview].dbo.Posts as CrPosts
        on  CrUsers.Id = CrPosts.OwnerUserId
        and CrPosts.PostTypeId = @questionPost
    inner join [StackOverflow].dbo.Posts as SoPosts
        on  SoUsers.Id = SoPosts.OwnerUserId
        and SoPosts.PostTypeId = @questionPost

    /*Bring in tags so we can try to eliminate false matches
      due to unrelated posts potentially being posted by the same
      user on 2 different sites within our scoped time period.*/
    inner join [StackExchange.Codereview].dbo.PostTags as CrPT
        on CrPosts.Id = CrPT.PostId
    inner join [StackExchange.Codereview].dbo.Tags as CrTags
        on CrPT.TagId = CrTags.Id
    inner join [StackOverflow].dbo.PostTags as SoPT
        on SoPosts.Id = SoPT.PostId
    inner join [StackOverflow].dbo.Tags as SoTags
        on  SoPT.TagId = SoTags.Id

where 
    /*Q was first posted on SO, then later on CR*/
    SoPosts.CreationDate < CrPosts.CreationDate

    /*Q was posted on CR within a certain number of minutes after being posted on SO*/
    and datediff(minute, SoPosts.CreationDate, CrPosts.CreationDate) <= @minutesFromSoPostToCrPost

    /*Match at least one language tag from CR->SO per post
      Note: We use `select distinct` on the query against #CrossPosts
        due to SEDE timing out if attempting to do it during this query.*/
    and CrTags.TagName = SoTags.TagName
    and exists (
        select 1 from #LanguageTags as Langs
        where CrTags.TagName = Langs.TagName
    )

    /*Apply filter based on character count difference of the body of both questions.*/
    and abs(len(CrPosts.Body) - len(SoPosts.Body)) <= @maximumCharacterCountDifferenceAllowed
;
/*Use this query to view full result set, or modify it 
  according to your needs to aggregate from the #CrossPosts table.*/
select distinct *
from #CrossPosts
order by [SO Created] desc;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Style

I like your style.  I don't mind reading keywords in lowercase.  I
think it's easier on the eyes, but then again, I'm fairly used to
case-sensitive languages with lowercase keywords and syntax
highlighting.

I'm also very fond of the prefix column aliases as opposed to the
postfix `AS Alias` style that is mainstream.

Bug if I *would* have to nitpick: the hanging comma in the `create table`
statement messes with the alignment of the column names.  There :)

## Filter-join on lookup table

The joins on both `Tags` tables is very deeply nested.  Which means,
that for each and every `Post`, SQL will join with each and every
`PostTag` (which is unavoidable, because they are needed in an
unfortunate m-to-n match-and-filter), and then for each of those, it
will join with the `Tags` table.

The `Tags` table is actually not needed in this join.  We can
pre-lookup all the tags that we want to use, by adding their
respective `TagId` values to the `#LanguageTags` temp table as
follows:

```
create table #LanguageTags (
    TagName varchar(35) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
    , CrTagId int
    , SoTagId int
    , constraint pk_#LanguageTags primary key (TagName)
);
go
insert into #LanguageTags (TagName)
values
  ('applescript'),
  ('asp.net-mvc-3'),
  ('bash'),
  ('brainfuck'),
  ('c'),
  ('c#'),
  ('c++'),

  /*SNIP...*/

  ('sql'),
  ('swift'),
  ('wolfram-mathematica'),
  ('xslt');
go
update Langs
   set CrTagId = CrTags.Id
     , SoTagId = SoTags.Id
  from #LanguageTags Langs
 inner join [StackExchange.CodeReview].dbo.Tags as CrTags
         on CrTags.TagName = Langs.TagName
 inner join [StackOverflow].dbo.Tags as SoTags
         on SoTags.TagName = Langs.TagName;
```

Now we can use this table to filter tags that we want to see by
`TagId`, and we can also join the posts from both sites to a single
table now.

## SEDE and cross database queries

It seems that SEDE is not really optimized to join the large database
tables to temp tables.  So when we put the join described above inside
the fetching query, we get a timeout.  The solution: store the `TagId`
values in the temp table:

```
select
  -- SNIP
  , [Tags] = CrPosts.Tags
  , [CrTagId] = CrPT.TagId
  , [SoTagId] = SoPT.TagId
```

and then filter-and-distinct on the `#LanguageTags` table in the final
query:

```
select distinct
       CP.[Primary Stack]
     , CP.[Primary User]
     , CP.[SO Original]
     , CP.[CR Xpost]
     , CP.[CharCountDiff]
     , CP.[SO Score]
     , CP.[CR Score]
     , CP.[SO Status]
     , CP.[CR Status]
     , CP.[DugaComments?]
     , CP.[SO Answers]
     , CP.[CR Answers]
     , CP.[SO Accept?]
     , CP.[CR Accept?]
     , CP.[SO Created]
     , CP.[Minutes to Xpost]
     , CP.[Tags]
     , CP.[CrTagId]
     , CP.[SoTagId]
  from #CrossPosts CP
    /*Match at least one language tag from CR->SO per post.*/
 inner join #LanguageTags as Langs
         on Langs.SoTagId = CP.SoTagId
        and Langs.CrTagId = CP.CrTagId
 order by [SO Created] desc;
```

Turns out that this is quite a bit faster, as the query now returns

> 1130 rows returned in 4166 ms